# Simple xml doesnt support for loop into foreach

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, simplexml

I have the following script that reads XML. But it stops after the for loop. If i remove the loop it runs perfect.

What do i do wrong or can i achieve this in an other way?

**Script**:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

foreach($xml->product as $child){
    echo 'Title:'.$child->name.'<br>';//title
    echo 'Price:'.$child->price.'<br>';//title
    echo 'image:'.$child->images->image.'<br>';//image
    echo 'category:'.$child->categories->category.'<br>';//categorie

    foreach( $child->properties->property as $property ){            
        if( $child->properties->property->attributes()->name =='brand'){
            echo $child->properties->property->value.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**:

```
<product ID="000000000000052993">
    <name> Title product</name>
    <price currency="EUR">29.99</price>
    <URL>http://www.url.nl</URL>
    <images>
        <image>product/5/2/52993_2.jpg</image>
    </images>
    <description><![CDATA[description.]]>
    </description>
    <categories>
        <category>catt</category>
    </categories>
    <properties>
        <property name="brand">
            <value>PHILIPS</value>
        </property>
        <property name="deliveryTime">
            <value>5</value>
        </property>
        <property name="User1">
        </property>
        <property name="User2">
        </property>
        <property name="shipping_cost">
            <value>0.00</value>
        </property>
        <property name="User3">
        </property>
        <property name="EAN">
            <value>8727900831733</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <variations/>
</product>
```

Comment: Put it in to an array should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it another foreach loop:

```
foreach( $child->properties as $property ){
    if( $property->attributes()->name == 'brand'){
        echo $property->value;
    }
    if( $property->attributes()->name == 'deliveryTime'){
        echo $property->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to filter on the $child->properties->property[$x]->attributes()->name , is that also possible whit a foreach?

Comment: Yes it is. What are you trying to achieve, and I will provide the code to you.

Comment: I want to filter on brand and deliveryTime like the for loop

Comment: No worries Bas - I'm happy I could help.